# ArcMap Model Builder Layers and Variables

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

I am new to Model Builder in ArcMap.

I have made a model to automatically calculate Land Surface Temperature (LST) by using Landsat 8 imagery. 
The issue is that the model doesn't fully run towards a result and I presume that it is due to the fact that when I've made the model, the name of the original file remained in the core of the model, so the name of the file needs to be the same if I want the model to give me results. This means that I have to rename every input data to fit the original name for the files.

How can I make the model to run without renaming the files? I remained stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the model? Double click the blue input ellipses and change the input. Or is this what you mean by renaming the files?

Comment: The model builder is composed of multiple Raster Calculator tools. The input for the model is the B10 Landsat 8 band and the NDVI. When I created the model, I needed to specify the path towards the input files and later, the files were specified in the Raster Calculator expression in order to calculate the necessary layers to serve as input again in the other expressions. Here is the issue. Whenever I change the input location, the model doesn't run properly. I presume I need to specify some variables but I don't know exactly how to do this.